# Is the Simulator or Emulator closer to matching device?

Tags: emulation, tizen, tizen-web-simulator

When I run my web application on the Tizen Web Simulator and the Tizen Emulator using the same resolution (HD 720x1280) and density (DPI), the display does not match. Which one is closer to the display on the actual Tizen device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tizen Emulator is closer to the actual device because does an actual emulation so it has an OS image build on it.

Web Simulator is simulating the API, the Web Runtime, and some of the connectivity using Chromium's Webkit engine. It is a simulated environment and there is support only fort the HTML5 applications and not for the native applications.

From my experience with the Tizen Web application API, Tizen Emulator was closer to the actual device compared with the simulator.

Answer (score 1):

There is a scale menu for Tizen Emulator. You can find context menu when you click to right mouse button on the tizen emulator. 4 scales available.

- 1x
- 3/4x
- 1/2x
- 1/4x

'1x' is closer to actual Tizen device. Tizen simulator display is similar '1/2x' scale of tizen emulator for me.

Answer (score 1):

The Emulator is indeed closer to the device display than the simulator.
However, if you want to see how your app would look on a device, why not flash the Tizen image on a device?
they can be found here, and i'm sure instructions are there also:

http://download.tizen.org/releases/2.1/tizen-2.1/